# Is there a faster way to calculate Abs[z]^2 numerically?

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, complex

Here I'm not interested in accuracy (see [13614](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13614/26598)) but rather in raw speed. You'd think that for a complex machine-precision number `z`, calculating `Abs[z]^2` should be faster than calculating `Abs[z]` because the latter requires a square root whereas the former does not. Yet it's not so:

```
s = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10^7, 2}].{1, I};
Developer`PackedArrayQ[s]
(* True *)
Abs[s]^2; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.083337 *)
Abs[s]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.033179 *)
```

This indicates that `Abs[z]^2` is really calculated by summing the squares of real and imaginary parts, taking a square root (for `Abs[z]`), and then re-squaring (for `Abs[z]^2`).

Is there a faster way to compute `Abs[z]^2`? Is there a hidden equivalent to the [GSL's](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/index.html) [`gsl_complex_abs2`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/complex.html#properties-of-complex-numbers) function? The source code of this GSL function is simply to return `Re[z]^2+Im[z]^2`; no fancy tricks.

Comment: Here's an even slower way: (Re[#]^2 + Im[#]^2) & /@ s. And even slower still: Total[ReIm[#]^2] & /@ s

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's `` Internal`AbsSquare ``:

```
s = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10^7, 2}].{1, I};
foo = Internal`AbsSquare[s]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
murf = Abs[s]^2; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(*
  0.022909
  0.063441
*)

foo == murf
(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Ah yes precisely what I was looking for, many thanks Michael! Is there a repository of such tricks?

Comment: @Roman I was just looking.  I thought there was a post about useful ``Internal` `` functions, but I couldn't find it just now.  The context contains some useful numerical functions like `Log1p` and `Expm1`. ``Statistics`Library` `` also contains some nice, well-programmed functions.

Comment: @MichaelE2 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/805/what-are-some-useful-undocumented-mathematica-functions

Comment: @ChrisK That must be it! Thanks.

Comment: I’m going digging for Internal functions tonight! Is there some large difference in precisely *how* this function operated faster than the others? Just optimized for it?

Comment: @CATrevillian I would have thought it was in the MKL (Intel Math Kernel Library), but I didn't find it there.  I guess I don't know.

Comment: @CATrevillian it's such a simple operation (at least in the GSL source code) that I'd look for it in the icc/gcc/clang optimization capabilities directly, not in the MKL.

Comment: @CATrevillian the `Abs` function likely operates by calling [hypot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypot) which is safer but slower than just taking the square root of `AbsSquare`. `AbsSquare`, on the other hand, is likely expressed directly as `re*re+im*im` in assembly, or a vectorized version thereof: with the [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org) I find that all x86-64 compilers express this function as `mulsd xmm0,xmm0; mulsd xmm1,xmm1; addsd xmm0, xmm1` even at `-O3` level, which is a literal translation without frills or optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

for v5.2, s Conjugate[s] is fast too, ref the pic:

> 

[image]

Comment: On my computer, `Re[s*Conjugate[s]]` is about five to ten times slower than ``Internal`AbsSquare[s]``. What is your `$Version` and what CPU do you have?

Comment: Hi, people here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely they will engage with your posts.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful. -- BTW, have you seen `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10^7, 2}]`? It's much faster on my machine.  Ditto for `RandomComplex[]`.

Comment: @Roman Re[] is unnecessary, though it's very fast. My version is very old, it's v5.2. So there's no Internal`AbsSquare[].

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, man. My version is v5.2. This code is so simple that I had no motivation to paste text version at that moment. Sorry.

Comment: Maybe it's worth adding the version info to your answer.  It turns out that I don't have the ``Statistics`NormalDistribution`` package (in V12.1.1), I suppose because it's been replaced by top-level statistics functions some versions ago.